# date.setHours() function does not fully set the time to zero

Tags: javascript, date, visual-studio-code

I am using the "MongoDB for VS Code" plugin in Visual Studio Code (v1.49.0) and am trying to reset the time of a Date object to 00:00:00:000 in the MongoDB Playground.

Here is the code:

```
var thisMonth = new Date();
thisMonth.setDate(1);
thisMonth.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
thisMonth;
```

However, the value output for thisMonth is:

```
2020-09-01T06:00:00.000Z
```

and not 2020-09-01T**00**:00:00.000Z as expected. This happens regardless of when the Date object is created. Does anyone else have experience or know why this might be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Result in `thisMonth`? Add actual output to question.

Comment: @D.SM thisMonth was set to 2020-09-22T06:00:00.000Z after the above two lines of code. I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: You did, but you did not provide actual output as it was rendered.

Comment: @D.SM I added the output, as requested.

Comment: If you live in north america this output is correct and as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB will always use UTC time (UTC-0 or Zulu/Zero time).

The hours you set are according to your local timezone, so in this case most likely North America (UTC-6). The result is given with a `Z` on the end indicating it is Zulu time (zero time).
To get the offset on your local machine you can use `thisMonth.getTimezoneOffset();`

To set the time to UTC time you use `thisMonth.setUTCHours(0);`

You will see that when setting the time to UTC time `0` you will actually get the `0` result you are looking for.

MongoDB does not have an understanding of timezones.

Comment: I tried the setUTCHours() approach and was able to get the output I expected. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to MongoDB but normal JavaScript behaviour. See [`Date#setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

> The setHours() method sets the hours for a specified date according to **local time** [...].

MongoDB transforms dates into their UTC representation before storing them. And you (or your server) seem to be located in a -6:00 time zone. The actual moment in time is correct, you are just seeing a representation that might not be what you expected.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I intend to use the date I create to $match dates that are greater than 2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z, so I need to make sure it is the very start of the month. To verify, you are saying that it is, just represented in a way I don't expect, right?

Comment: it is Z time as indicated in your output. Not what you expect but exactly how it will be stored in MongoDB.